# Using Xpath over return value of an XSLT extension method

Tags: c#, xslt, xpath, methods

I have an xml being returned by an extension method. Can some please help me to use `<xsl:for-each>` on this xml.

```java
public class CustomObj
{
    //function that gets called from XSLT
    public XPathNodeIterator GetResultTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Table1");

        table.Columns.Add("SourceCity");
        table.Columns.Add("DestinationCity");
        table.Columns.Add("Fare");

        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "New York", "Las Vegas", "100" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "New York", "London", "200" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "New York", "New Delhi", "250" });

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        table.WriteXml(writer);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Root");
        root.InnerXml = writer.ToString();
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        return doc.CreateNavigator().Select("root");
    }
}
```

I want to iterate over this xml. Some one please help. I am new to XSLT and would appreciate if you can provide example on the given xml itself.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the XML this code outputs..

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are two things to note**:

1. It is much more natural to apply the transformation to the result of invoking the method `GetResultTable()` than to get its result via an extension function.
2. As written the `GetResultTable()` method doesn't return any node at all: in the statement

--

```
   return doc.CreateNavigator().Select("root");
```

the `Select()` method doesn't select anything as there is no `root` element in `doc`. The element named `Root` isn't selected, because XML and XPath are case-sensitive.

**Another observation is that it isn't necessary at all to use `xsl:for-each` within an XSLT transformation** -- this is considered not a good practice in most cases.

**Having said that, here is the complete code for what this question asks for**:

```
namespace TestXml
{
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.XPath;
    using System.Xml.Xsl;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CustomObj co = new CustomObj();
            XPathNodeIterator xpni = co.GetResultTable();

            XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
            xslt.Load(@"..\..\My.xslt");

            XsltArgumentList xargs = new XsltArgumentList();
            xargs.AddExtensionObject("my:extension", co);

            XmlDocument fakeDoc = new XmlDocument();
            fakeDoc.LoadXml("<t/>");

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

            xslt.Transform(fakeDoc.CreateNavigator(), xargs, sw);

            string result = sw.ToString();

            Console.Write(result);
        }
    }

    public class CustomObj
    {    //function that gets called from XSLT    
        public XPathNodeIterator GetResultTable()    
        {        
            DataTable table = new DataTable("Table1");        
            table.Columns.Add("SourceCity");        
            table.Columns.Add("DestinationCity");        
            table.Columns.Add("Fare");        
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "New York", "Las Vegas", "100" });        
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "New York", "London", "200" });        
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "New York", "New Delhi", "250" });        
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();        
            table.WriteXml(writer);        
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();        
            XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Root");        
            root.InnerXml = writer.ToString();        
            doc.AppendChild(root);        
            return doc.CreateNavigator().Select("Root");    
        }
    }
}
```

**and the file `My.xslt`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:extension"
 exclude-result-prefixes="my">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>Source</td>
          <td>Destination</td>
          <td>Fare</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="my:GetResultTable()/*/Table1"/>
      </table>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Table1">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Table1/*">
    <td>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the application is executed, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Source</td>
      <td>Destination</td>
      <td>Fare</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>Las Vegas</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>New Delhi</td>
    <td>250</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```